# Function resize() from module moviepy isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm trying to write a small program and in it I want to resize a clip but the function ain't working for some reason.

```
import easygui
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

run = True

def video():
    clip = easygui.fileopenbox()
    clip = VideoFileClip(clip)
    clip.resize((1920, 1080))
    clip.preview(fps=60)

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                video()
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: How is it not working? does it shows an error? unexpected output?

Comment: No, it's working but it's as if the function resize wasn't there. I can run the program with or without it and the result will be the same (the window with the video will not be resized)

Answer (score 2):

I had to make `clip = clip.resize((x,y))` to make the size change.

Comment: This worked for me , thanks.